# How can I set or limit the number of cores that a trial is allowed to use?

Tags: machine-learning, ray, cpu-cores, rllib, ray-tune

I am trying to run a trial in RayTune, for which I want to test how the number of cores I throw at the problem affects calculation times. I tried `ray.init(num_cpus=foo)`, but it just utilises all cores on the machine nonetheless, regardless of the number I put in there.

I can't try the `tune.with_resources()`, as I am working with RLlib and need to specify the trainable as a string name of the algorithm (e.g. "PPO"). The documentation is also quite nontransparent on the topic. How can I overcome this?